# How to set an external GPU "only GPU" as the primary GPU on a desktop?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hdmi, gpu, desktop

I built a desktop/mining rig. After I got everything setup, I learned that my I5 CPU does not have an integrated graphic card. This means that I am unable to utilize the HDMI port found on the motherboard.

I installed a NVIDIA 3070 graphic card on the machine and tried to plugin the HDMI directly into it. I don't really want to have to replace the CPU.

Question, is there a way to make my only NVIDIA 3070 GPU as the primary card so I can utilize the HDMI port on the motherboard? Like, is there an additional cable that I can connect from the GPU to the motherboard that would make the motherboard's HDMI port usable?

Comment: As far as I know the mainboard HDMI port can only be connected to the CPU. The same is true for an onboard USB-C port with alternate displayport data capability. On some mainboards there is even an displayport input socket for connecting a graphics card with that port because without CPU with graphics it won't work.

Comment: Why does it have to be the motherboard port? What's wrong with the port on the 3070 graphics card?

Comment: This question is confusing.  I am not aware of any 30 Series Nvidia card that doesn’t have at least one HDMI port.  So why do you feel forced to use the HDMI on the motherboard.  I have bad news, that port only works with a CPU, that has an iGPU.

Comment: @Ramhound the GPU does have an HDMI port that I can plug directly into it. I am running into an issue with this Desktop where (every time I shut it down "and unplug the power" the PC does not turn on any more. I have to remove the cemos battery and reset the bios for it to work. I was told plugging HDMI directly to the GPU is causing this issue. So I cam trying to find a work around.

Comment: You were told a problem solved by removing and replacing the CMOS battery (with the same battery) would be solved by using the iGPU?  Why wouldn’t you just not replace the CMOS battery?

Comment: @Ramhound I actually did that. same result. In fact, now I can't even get the GPU to display anything to the screen

Answer (score 1):

No.

The on-board HDMI is connected to the CPU integrated graphics controller. It connects directly to the CPU itself.

There is no way to get a display output from that port without having built-in graphics on your CPU.

It has nothing to do with whether your 3070 is your "primary" card and everything to do with having actual hardware (a GPU built in to your CPU) connected to that port.

You shouldn't want to use that port anyway in normal use because it would be the CPUs graphics processor driving that port and not your 3070. In order to do pretty much anything your computer would be rendering frames on your 3070, copying the data to the CPU graphics over PCIe and then displaying from that. It's not optimal unless you know and accept the performance costs.